# UIScrollView bounds have not yet resized in "viewDidLoad"

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, uiscrollview

I have a UIViewController subclass whose view is configured in a NIB file. The view has a UIScrollView subview.

The UIScrollView takes up almost its entire NIB file but it's superview is added as a subview to a much smaller view (configured in a different NIB) - e.g. the UIScrollView is 80% the height of it's own NIB but ends up only being 10% the height of the application's window.

When I call [scrollView bounds].size.height in the viewController's viewDidLoad method, I get the height of the scrollView relative to it's own NIB, rather than the height it ends up resizing to as dictated by its superviews (e.g. 80% of the window's height rather than 10%).

If I call [scrollView bounds].size.height later on (e.g. to handle a rotation event), I get the correct value.

How can I get the correctly re-sized value initially?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried dealing with it in `viewWillAppear:` or `viewDidAppear`?

Comment: Using "viewDidAppear" worked. In the "main" view controller I allocate and initiate the "scroll" view controller (whose NIB includes the UIScrollView). After adding the scroll view controller's view as a subview of the main view controller's view, I called viewDidAppear on the scroll view controller and handled the bounds retrieval there. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I'm following, there must be some point after the view controller is loaded at which you grab the .view and insert it into the other subview? If so then the bounds will be adjusted then. You can't get them in viewDidLoad because the view has no way of knowing what you'll do with it in the future. Even if your call to insert it as a subview is the very first thing you do after loading the view controller, it's the view accessor that'll cause the view to load and hence the viewDidLoad, all before you've actually put the view anywhere.

Since bounds has a getter and a setter, it should be key-value coding compliant, in which case you can use viewDidLoad to register an observer on bounds and do whatever it is you need to do when the bounds change.